# Doctrine lock tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using [Doctrine with Symfony 4.4](https://symfony.com/index.php/doc/4.4/doctrine.html).

I have a database with two tables:

BookRead: bookid userid

BookWrite: bookid userid

An user cannot read and write a book in the same time. But the users can read more than one books but one book can be written by one user at time.

I have two classes one for table like this:

```
class BookReadRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{

   public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
   {
      parent::__construct($registry, BookRead::class);
   }

   public function query1($user, &$bookRead)
   {
     try
     {
            $this->_em->beginTransaction();
            $query = $this->_em->createQuery
            (
                "SELECT d 
                FROM App\Entity\BookReadd
                WHERE 
                d.bookid= :user
                "
            )
                ->setParameter("user", $user);
            $query->setLockMode(LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
            $dogs= $query->getResult();
        

        } catch (Exception $e)
        {
            return false;
        }
     return true
  }

public function unLock()
    {
        if (!$this->_em->getConnection()->isTransactionActive())
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (!$this->_em->getConnection()->commit())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The run speudo code:

```
(new BookReadRepository ($registry))->query1($user, $bookReads);
//checks
(new BookWriteRepository ($registry))->query1($user, $bookWrites);
//checks

 $this->managerRegistry->getManager()->persist($bookWrite); //or bookRead
 $this->managerRegistry->getManager()->flush();

(new BookReadRepository ($registry))->unLock(); 
(new BookWriteRepository ($registry))->unLock();
```

I wish to check if an user (with a book) is not present to other table in order to set in the other table.

Ex:

```
A -> ask if the user is not on BookRead so insert in the BookWrite.
B -> ask if the user is not on BookWrite so insert in the BookRead.
```

The problem is:

if A askes if the Lucy user is not BookRead and just a moment to insert to BookWrite, B insert to BookRead because Lucy is not on BookRead? I will have Lucy on two tables.

My idea is:

```
In order to insert on BookWrite 
Lock BookRead table -> checks
Lock BookWrite table -> checks and insert on BookWrite 
UnLock BookWrite and BookRead 

In order to insert on BookRead 
Lock BookRead table -> checks
Lock BookWrite table -> checks and insert BookRead 

UnLock BookWrite and BookRead
```

The goal is:
the users can read more than one books (on read books table) but one book can be written by one user at time (on write book).

But my code don't work and I am not able to understand the way.

Comment: Sounds like it should be a single BookRepository with read/write flag with `bookid,user` being a primary key (and therefore unique). Then just attempt an insert, catch the duplicate key exception, and that means they existed already. Or going further [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to set the flag appropriately on insert.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but in reality the goal is to block the two tables because the real case is more complicate: In reality the One user can read more than one book but one book can be written by one user at time

Comment: I have update the problem

Comment: I can't quite grasp the unlock table as a transaction thing. Locking table in a sql term is excessive. Maybe its a doctrine thing. With two tables you'd, `start transaction; select .. bookread where .. lock in share mode; {if no result} insert into bookwrite ...; commit`. The `select lock in share mode` will introduce a gap lock so it can't be inserted. Something attempting the reverse operation at the same time will deadlock.

Comment: But with another table I have another problem because I have to do a spining loop on this table in order to test if I can read the others table. I have supposed that in Doctrine there is a way to block tables.

Comment: I don't get where a spinning loop comes into this. Locking tables is a bad paradigm, focus on the right transaction logic to introduce the row level locks you need. An alternate is a [before insert trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) that [raises an error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) if the user is in the other table.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I have to do it. In addition I don't know if I can put a trigger in the db beacuse I only can use the php to interact with it.

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/transactions.html - adapt isolation level, use transactions. you need at least repeatable read, maybe even serializable. for both bookread and bookwrite (insert/update) you always need to read in BOTH table to make the id-restricted read lock. do avoid deadlocks you should always lock in the same order. lock mechanisms vary between databases, don't know how mysql locks exactly. maybe efficiently, maybe table lock (bad)